# add another category to the beautiful Radar Chart

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts, amcharts4

Using **amCharts 4** library, I want to create a Radar graph exactly like this:

[image]

As you see there are two categories compared and each one has bullets all around right?

So far I have this:

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

/* Create chart instance */
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);

/* Add data */
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501
}, {
  "country": "Czechia",
  "litres": 301
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 266
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 336
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 290
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 325
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 40
}];

/* Create axes */
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(2);
valueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.fillOpacity = 0.05;

/* Create and configure series */
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "litres";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Sales";
series.strokeWidth = 3;

}); // end am4core.ready()
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

In my code there is no bullets and I don't know how to add another category.

**Please note I want to use amCharts 4 for some reasons not amcharts 5.**

**how can I do these two changes?**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head></head>
<style></style>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px;height: 600px;"></div>
    <script>
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
        // Themes end

        /* Create chart instance */
        var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);

        /* Add data */
        chart.data = [{
            "country": "Lithuania",
            "litres": 501
        }, {
            "country": "Czechia",
            "litres": 301
        }, {
            "country": "Ireland",
            "litres": 266
        }, {
            "country": "Germany",
            "litres": 165
        }, {
            "country": "Australia",
            "litres": 139
        }, {
            "country": "Austria",
            "litres": 336
        }, {
            "country": "UK",
            "litres": 290
        }, {
            "country": "Belgium",
            "litres": 325
        }, {
            "country": "The Netherlands",
            "litres": 40
        }];

        /* Create axes */
        var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
        categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";

        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        valueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(2);
        valueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.fillOpacity = 0.05;

        /* Create and configure series */
        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries());
        series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        series.dataFields.valueY = "litres";
        series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
        series.name = "Sales";
        series.strokeWidth = 3;

        
        var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries());
        series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        series1.dataFields.valueY = "litres";
        series1.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
        series1.name = "Sales";
        series1.strokeWidth = 3;

        series1.data = [{
            "country": "Lithuania",
            "litres": 200
        }, {
            "country": "Czechia",
            "litres": 350
        }, {
            "country": "Ireland",
            "litres": 250
        }, {
            "country": "Germany",
            "litres": 100
        }, {
            "country": "Australia",
            "litres": 150
        }, {
            "country": "Austria",
            "litres": 350
        }, {
            "country": "UK",
            "litres": 250
        }, {
            "country": "Belgium",
            "litres": 290
        }, {
            "country": "The Netherlands",
            "litres": 140
        }];

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```